# Replace the text from an Excel Sheet in a File Using Python

Tags: python, excel, replace, str-replace

I am very new in Python and I am  trying to figure out how to write a code which searches a text file for a string in a cell in Excel sheet and replace that string with a consequtive cell from the same row.

```
+-----------+------------+--------+
|    A      |    B       |    C   |
+-----------+------------+--------+
|    a      |    a_1     |  a_2   |
|    b      |    b_1     |  b_2   |
|    c      |    c_1     |  c_2   |
+-----------+------------+--------+
```

In the text_file it's written **"This is a_xyz"**.

What I try to do is, to create multiple text files like **"This is a_1"** and **"This is a_2"** and save them automatically. Of course there will be more rows and columns.

Tricky thing for me is, the string is **"a"** in Excel sheet, but it needs to replace the whole **"a_xyz"** in which **"a"** is present.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you'd probably want to use something like this library https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
to open up the file. as far as I'm aware excel's format is not easily translated to text (try opening it in notepad and see for yourself :)). it's basically binary data. Go and read the docs at the link I posted and you should be able to figure out how to iterate over each row. as a first step try saving the exactly same excel file by going through them row by row. once you've done that, just edit the place where you're doing the save so that it swaps those columns. cheers